# How to display a 3D object (*.stl file) using Django

Tags: javascript, django, google-chrome-extension, django-views, obfuscation

I have a website developed using `Django`. Several `3D object` files (`*.stl` files) are loaded from the administration. I would like to add the following two functionalities.

1- Being able to view `3D objects`, both for an administrator and for a regular user.
2- In case of being a regular user, the object is only downloadable, under some conditions (for example if the user pay for the article.)

The following site is a good benchmark of what I want. [sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/latte-rigged-49669769bd014aa7a0af228ee5474e62)

I don't even know how to proceed, any comment would be welcome.

**UPDATE**

The comment made by @Dumidor may be part of the solution. If I didn't misunderstand, we would be able to view the `3D object` using `JavaScript`. In the case of seeing it from the administration site there are no problems. But in the case of being a regular user, the following question arises. Can someone get the `3D object`, if they edit the `JavaScript` code? How can I prevent it, if this is the case?

**UPDATE**

Continuing with my search, I came to two possible solutions. One is `Obfuscation` of the `JavaScript` code, but I understand that it doesn't completely solve the problem, because it just makes it more difficult for someone else to change the code. The other possible solution is to use `extensions` like the one in `Chrome`, to add a kind of extra layer of security, but it's just an idea and I would like if someone could tell me if it works, because I've never done one before, and therefore I don't even know how they work.

Comment: not sure about STL but gltf can be done https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-gltf-viewer you just need to find a good converter

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I was testing and it can be very helpful. Please check my updated question. Again thank!!.